# How do I add a variable to a JSON list in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks likes this:

```
{ "users":"John, admin"}
```

What I want is to be able to add a string into the "users" title.
So, basically, I want to allow users to input a new username and add it to this list. Take the following Python code:

```
newUserInfo = input("Enter a new username: ")
```

And then say I input "Michael"
Then the JSON file should look like this:

```
{ "users":"John, admin, Michael"}
```

I've tried the following:

```
with open(userFile, "a") as userobj:
newUserInfo = json.dump(allUserInfo["users": newUserInfo], userobj)
```

And It returns an error. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are aware that `{"users": ["John", "admin"]}` would be a much besser format?

Comment: I am now. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Append the name to the string:

```
import json
s = '''{"users":"John, admin"}'''
data = json.loads(s)
newUserInfo = input("Enter a new username: ")
data['users'] += ', ' + newUserInfo
s2 = json.dumps(data)
print(s2)
```

Output:

```
{"users": "John, admin, Michael"}
```

But a more natural way to use JSON would be represent the names in a list:

```
import json

s = '''{"users":["John","admin"]}'''

data = json.loads(s)
newUserInfo = input("Enter a new username: ")
data['users'].append(newUserInfo)
s2 = json.dumps(data)
print(s2)
```

Output:

```
{"users": ["John", "admin", "Michael"]}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help!